# Does the NPVIC only take effect once enough states sign for it to have legal force?

Tags: united-states, electoral-college, na-po-vo-inter-co

15 state legislatures plus the District of Columbia have passed legislation enacting the [National Popular Vote Interstate Compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Popular_Vote_Interstate_Compact), as described on Wikipedia. However, this represents only 72.6% of the 270 electoral votes necessary to give the compact "legal force".

Will the states that have signed on to it be appointing their electors based on the NPV regardless of whether enough further states sign on to give it this "legal force"?

Or will the states that have signed on appoint their electors as usual until such "legal force" is attained?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.   The Compact does not come into effect until there are 270 Electoral Votes distributed among all signatories.  Presently, all signatories are assigning electors by a Winner Takes all First Past the Post system for their own state.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is 270 electoral votes

Comment: @MagnusJørgensen My Bad... got my mental math wrong.